# Failed to find attribute 'dp' in 'main'. Uploading on Heroku

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot, aiogram

This is Telegram bot with 3.3.0 aiogram.
The problem is that it works brilliant if I manualy run it on my PC via VS Code but Heroku says that there is a Fail and I can't find out why.

main.py:

```
import logging
import asyncio
from os import getenv
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types          # HERE IS IMPORTED DISPATCHER
from aiogram.enums import ParseMode
from aiogram.filters import Command
from bot.handlers.user_handlers import user_router

load_dotenv()

TOKEN = getenv("TOKEN")
API = getenv("API")

# routers
def register_routers(dp: Dispatcher) -> None:
    dp.include_router(user_router)

async def main() -> None:
    dp = Dispatcher()           # HERE IS THE DISPATCHER INITIALIZED
    register_routers(dp)

    #start bot
    bot = Bot(TOKEN, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

[my GitHub repository with this project](https://github.com/slaaay/crypto-bot)

[image: the project tree]
[image: requirements.txt]
[image: Heroku logs]

Deploying via Heroku CLI and tried via GitHub, the same mistake. That's my first time I've been uploading my telegram bot and I'm so sorry if there is a stupid mistake of mine but please help. I really don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Please include the full traceback error as text.